# Android change destination mac address

Tags: android, networking

Java(sun) restricts change of dst mac address. However the Android has a linux core, therefore with root theoretically, I suppose, we could manage to send ipv6 packet with header that mentions the destination  L2 address in C language.

Could you please give (or point to) an examples how to do that in Android, if possible.
Thank you!

Comment: IP headers know nothing about the layer-2 protocol used. If you use one of the layer-2 protocols that uses MAC addresses, then IP doesn't know anything about it. You seem to be confusing the network layers. When using IPv4, ARP will resolve a layer-3 address to a layer-2 address, and with IPv6, ND does the same. Sending a layer-3 packet to a different host will cause the packet to be dropped when it reaches layer-3 because the layer-3 address doesn't match what is configured on the host.

Comment: Let's ignore L3.
My question still remains the same. Could you please specify which buil-in c/c++ library in android I could use to send a raw data on L2 to the specific dest mac I want.

Comment: Unfortunately, such a recommendation is off-topic here. See the [help/on-topic]: "_Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it._"